# call the function in another class(c#)

Tags: c#, uwp

I am trying to migrate one of my macOS app to Windows UWP.

There is a requirement that I need to call the function in another class

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public bool isOk;
        public MainPage()
        {
            

        }
        public void doSomething(){

        };
        /*
        public static void doSomething(){

            isOk=false;// isOk is inaccessible

        };*/
    }

    public sealed partial class AnotherPage : Page
    {
        

        public AnotherPage()
        {
             //call doSomething() in MainPage

        }
    }

  
}
```

it is very easy to implement this in objective-c via protocol(interface)

but in c#, the mechanism of the interface is different from the objective-c protocol.

of course, I can use the code below

```
MainPage mainPage=new MainPage();
mainPage.dosomthing();
```

but I wonder if this is valid for Page object related to the XAML file.

or there is a common usage to call the function in another class?

Your comment welcome

Comment: If `doSomething()` contains logic that is not specific to `MainPage`, then the method should be in another class. If you want to call it without creating an object, you need to make the method `static`.

Comment: thanks, but for the function public static void doSomething(),  how can I access the property isOk in it

Comment: Static methods on class can't access non static members. Have to pass in a reference to the instance.

Comment: if I want to access the content of a Button  in MainPage from AnotherPage, does this mean that  is impossible

Comment: Nope it means you need to a reference the instance of main page.ie AnotherPage needs to know which MainPage instance it needs to call. The answer on here demonstrates one of the ways of doing that. There are several others.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE:  This is an answer to your question but from a design perspective this is bad.

You need a reference to the instantiated MainPage.  I'm sure there's one in the framework but for example just so this can be understood let's make a public static class to hold this reference.

```
public static class Global
{
    public static Page MainPage { get; set; }
}
```

Now in the MainPage constructor assign itself to this property of the static Global class.

```
public MainPage()
{
     Global.MainPage = this;
}
```

Now from any other page you can access it.

```
public AnotherPage()
{
     Global.MainPage.doSomething();
}
```